# Regex: not arbitrary non capturing group

Tags: .net, regex

I'm trying to write regex to cover all my cases.
I have to parse Xml and capture some properties.
Example:

```
<item p2="2"/>
<item p1="1" p2="2"/>
<item p1="1" p2="2" p3="3"/>
<item p1="1" p2="2" p3="3" p4="4"/>
<item p1="1" p2="2" p3="3" p4="4" p5="5"/>
```

I have to capture value of "p2" property and I know that "p2" will always be present in line.
Also I want to capture value of "p4" property which will not always be present.

At first I'm trying to satisfy first four cases(first 4 lines in example) and I wrote regular expression like this:

```
\<item.+?p2=\"(?<val1>\d+)".*?(?:p4=\"(?<val2>\d+)\")?\/\>
```

And it works fine. "val1" group always returns value. And "val2" group returns value if "p4" property were presented.

But to cover my last case:

```
<item p1="1" p2="2" p3="3" p4="4" p5="5"/>
```

I have modified my regular expression like this:

```
\<item.+?p2=\"(?<val1>\d+)".*?(?:p4=\"(?<val2>\d+)\")?.*?\/\>
______________________________________________________^^^
```

And I found that "val1" group still returns values, but "val2" group no more returns the values for all cases.

Could you tell me what I'm missed, and help to write regular expression to cover all my cases?

[Example here in Regex tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5C%3Citem.%2B%3Fp2%3D%5C%22(%3F%3Cval1%3E%5Cd%2B)%22.*%3F(%3F%3Ap4%3D%5C%22(%3F%3Cval2%3E%5Cd%2B)%5C%22)%3F.*%3F%5C%2F%5C%3E&i=%3Citem%20p2%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Citem%20p1%3D%221%22%20p2%3D%222%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Citem%20p1%3D%221%22%20p2%3D%222%22%20p3%3D%223%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Citem%20p1%3D%221%22%20p2%3D%222%22%20p3%3D%223%22%20p4%3D%224%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%3Citem%20p1%3D%221%22%20p2%3D%222%22%20p3%3D%223%22%20p4%3D%224%22%20p5%3D%225%22%2F%3E%0D%0A)

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but your time might be better invested in learning to use an XML parser.  Regex is not so good for XML parsing.

Comment: Using regex here will be a real hassle. Can you guarantee that the arguments will always in the same order? If not, you'll have to make an alternation for each possible order. Using an XML parser would be much more sane and safe.

Comment: I know that writing regex to parse Xml is not a good idea. And I'm already implement it using other instruments. But while my first implementation found this behaviour and I'm wondering how to implement it by regex. If you want I can rewrite example without Xml.

Comment: There's no need, as long as this doesn't go in production code you can be curious about regex all you want. But you might want to be aware that you'll systematically receive downvotes and dissuasive comments when asking something about regex + XML.

Comment: I'm not familiar at all with .NET regex flavour but you might want to try using the `?+` possessive quantifier for your `p4` fragment rather than a simple `?`.

Comment: Is it possible for the value of p2 to include the string 'p2="'?

Comment: To Martin Brown: no, values of all properties are integers, and order of all properties will be the same.(For example: "p2" will be always before "p4")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML is not a [Regular language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language) there for using Regular Expressions is not the way to go. You will also need a [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

There are many ways to do this, but personally I would load the XML document into an [XmlDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class and use the [SelectNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx) method with an [XPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx) query to find your list of items. Once you have that you can use a foreach on each found [XmlNode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the [Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) collection to get the data you want.

If you must do this using regular expressions what you need to do is put the last .*? inside the non-capturing group. What you have done is give the Regex permission to ommit the p4 patch and match .*? instead. By putting the .*? inside the group it removes this possibility. This is likely to be slow (it may even suffer from [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)) and it will not handle all the complexities of XML. Here is a program that demonstraits:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var regex = new Regex(@"
        \<item                  # Capture <item
        .+?                     # Capture one or more characters as few times as possible 
        p2=                     # Capture p2=
        \""                     # Capture opening quote
        (?<val1>\d+)            # Capture one or more decimal digits and put them in val1
        ""                      # Capture closing quote
        .*?                     # Capture zero or more characters as few times as possible
        (?:                     # Begin a non capturing group
            p4=                 # Capture p4=
            \""                 # Capture opening quote
            (?<val2>\d+)        # Capture one or more decimal digits and put them in val2
            \""                 # Capture closing quote
            .*?                 # Capture zero or more characters as few times as possible
        )?                      # Capture 0 or 1 p4s        
        />                      # Capture \>
        ", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

        Test(regex, @"<item p2=""2""/>", "2", string.Empty);
        Test(regex, @"<item p1=""1"" p2=""2""/>", "2", string.Empty);
        Test(regex, @"<item p1=""1"" p2=""2"" p3=""3""/>", "2", string.Empty);
        Test(regex, @"<item p1=""1"" p2=""2"" p3=""3"" p4=""4""/>", "2", "4");
        Test(regex, @"<item p1=""1"" p2=""2"" p3=""3"" p4=""4"" p5=""5""/>", "2", "4");
    }

    static void Test(Regex regex, string test, string p2, string p4)
    {
        Match m = regex.Match(test);

        string p2Group = m.Groups["val1"].Value;
        string p4Group = m.Groups["val2"].Value;

        Console.WriteLine("Test: '{0}'", test);
        Console.WriteLine("p2: '{0}' - {1}", p2Group, p2Group == p2 ? "Success" : "Fail");
        Console.WriteLine("p4: '{0}' - {1}", p4Group, p4Group == p4 ? "Success" : "Fail");
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that writing regex to parse Xml is not a good idea. And I'm already implement it using other instruments. But while my first implementation found this behaviour and I'm wondering how to implement it by regex. If you want I can rewrite example without Xml.

Comment: Write your example without Xml and I'll give you a better answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly that I wanted. Sorry, I can't even click "This answer is useful" because  I don't have reputation enough.